# Titebond III Ultimate for raised garden bed

Tags: glue, outdoor

I would like to use TB 3 Ultimate to glue stacks of 4"x4"x8' together in a overlapping configuration to make a 12" tall garden bed. With it hold up under Pacific NW east cascade weather? It rains 9 months of the year.

Comment: Is there a reason you think you should use glue instead of mechanical fasteners?

Comment: Very little about woodworking here. You might find more interest over at DIY SE, even though there is a bit of overlap. But in terms of _how_ to best make a raised garden bed, DIY will probably have some Q&A.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a overlapping configuration"?

Comment: @AlaskaMan I was thinking if wood glue works, then it save me the trouble to drill holes and the cost of hardware. Glue will also distribute the stress across the surfaces instead of just a few points with fasteners.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I was saying to lay the lumber like laying bricks. https://l.hdnux.com/350x235p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/178/242/87704739_XS.jpg

Comment: @RayCheng comments aren't really part of the question, and external links will be dead in an internet minute. Place images and edits in-line with an [edit] of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> With it hold up under Pacific NW east cascade weather?

Nobody can give you a definitive answer to this as there are too many maybes. If you want to use Titebond III the best advice is to read what Franklin themselves say about its properties on [their website](http://www.titebond.com) and make your own call.

If you have any reservations about using it — and I think you should have some — use a foaming polyurethane instead.

In addition to being reliably 100% waterproof polyurethanes offer these clear advantages:

- A longer open time, aiding assembly of the beds in one shot.
- Probably the chief reason to select them is they deal with wetter wood better. Franklin warn that wood with a higher moisture content (as is common with construction lumber and pressure-treated stock) can impair or even prevent the drying of PVAs.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use TB 3 Ultimate to glue stacks of 4"x4"x8' together in a overlapping configuration to make a 12" tall garden bed.

Why do you want to use Titebond 3? It's waterproof and all, but it doesn't fill the gaps that are sure to happen with rough lumber like typical 4x4" stock.

You'd be far better off with construction adhesive. Better than that would be to put the parts in position, drill holes through the stack, and drive a length of rebar through the holes and into the ground.

Comment: I was going to recommend construction adhesive as well, actually had it written in, except that I was reminded of how short its open time can be as I was composing my Answer.